# Upload of Webcam picture with ajax: Sometimes the image is only partially saved. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, upload, webcam

I work on a web application where I take a picture of the customer (actually two pictures) and upload it with Ajax.
I do a base64 encode before the upload and the data is quite huge (1.4MB)
Ajax calls a php script turns over the data and php saves it in a mysql database. Most of the times it is working ok, but sometimes only a part of the picture is saved. Each time a similar amount of the pictures is saved. So when I have 30kb of the first pic in the db I also have 30kb of the second picture.

What am I missing and why do I get fragments in my db?
Also: The amount of data ist quite huge (about 1.4-1.7mb per picture)
How can I reduce that?

I split the process. A first php script gets the record data and a second is called for every picture.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax/upload_facefit_session_image.php",
      data: {
          session_name: name,
          imgBase64_user: data_user
      },
      success: function (response) {
        success = 1;
        console.log(response);
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.status);
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
      }
  });
```

I haven't seen any errors on my sessions yet. But I've seen the crippled data in the db.

Comment: What kind of column you store your data?

Comment: Do you mean longblob?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I learned that I showed a button to reload and start over too soon, while the data was uploading in the background. I solved it for now by showing the button later.

I'm still working on compressing the data because 2x1.4-1.7mb is way too much